# Check multiple variables in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have 5 variables and want to use the one with the highest value. How do I do this in batch?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
set Var1=1
set Var2=1
set Var3=1
set Var4=2
set Var5=1
```

If I want to check all the variables then echo the highest, is there a command for that, or will I have to use a lot of if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a max=Var1
for /l %%v in (1,1,5) do if !Var%%v! GTR !max! set /a max=Var%%v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid many IF statements by using a loop:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "max=0"
for %%V in (var1 var2 var3 var4 var5) do if !%%V! gtr !max! set "max=!%%V!"
```

Or if the variables really have names as you describe, then you can use the FOR /L loop as in Joey's answer.

Or if the variables all begin with the same prefix, and you know that no other variables begin with that same prefix:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "max=0"
for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%A in ('set var') do if %%B gtr !max! set "max=%%B"
```